# How to use custom font icons in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fonts

> [Dublicate from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/cui3hb/how_to_use_custom_font_icons_in_react/)

I faced a problem when I wanted to use my font icons created on https://glyphter.com/.
 My goal is to load font icons before rendering the page.

**Question:** What is the best way to use font icons in a React app? <s>No FontAwesome</s>

Comment: I don't think that there is any event for web fonts, they are just loaded you will never know when they are loaded and when they are loading. So you always will have broken icons then after a while it will load, the only thing you can do is delay and show some kind of loader.

Comment: @jcubic, I thought so, alas

Comment: Except there's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSetLoadEvent, and typekit's [webfont loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#readme) as fallback. However, if you're using react, and you're using a font for icons, there is literally no reason to serve a full font for a set of _known assets_  - why serve an entire font when you're only using 10 icons? Extract them and use normal images instead, for maximum compatibility?